# CSS dropdown menu won't position correctly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-position, positioning

Hoping someone can please help! I'm creating a dropdown menu under shop and I just can't figure out 1.) Why can't I resize the container that's holding the subitems and 2.) How to move the subitems over to the left, aligned under the Shop btn. It's driving me crazy!! Thanks so much for taking a look

```css
/* Generated by Font Squirrel (http://www.fontsquirrel.com) on September 4, 2014 */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'revolution';
    src: url('../fonts/revolution/revolution-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/revolution/revolution-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/revolution/revolution-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/revolution/revolution-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/revolution/revolution-webfont.svg#revolutionrevolution') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}



/*************************
Start Styling
*************************/

body#pages {
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-image: url('../images/pages_bg.jpg');
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}


#wrapper_2 {
 width: 1024px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: auto;
 
}

/*************************
SHOP MENU
*************************/
#shop_menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: -90px;
    margin-top: 42px;
}

#shop_menu ul{
    padding-left: 235px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#shop_menu li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 3px;
}

#shop_menu a{
    font-family: 'revolution';
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #0c5066; /*Teal Blue*/
    text-decoration: none;
}

#shop_menu a:hover{
    color: #d8512b; /*Orange Red*/
    
}

/*----- DROP DOWN -----*/

#dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.drop-nav {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.drop-nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
#dropdown:hover > .drop-nav {
  display: block;
  background-color: #888;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Product Page - SHOP</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesTEST.css" />
  </head>

<body id="pages">

  <div id="wrapper_2">

        <!--MENU -->
   <div id="shop_menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="mockup.html">Home</a></li>
     <li>&#124;</li>
     <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
     <li>&#124;</li>
    <!--DROP DOWN --> 
     <li id="dropdown"><a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
      <ul class="drop-nav">
       <li><a href="#">Womens</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Mens</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Womens Plus</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Mens Plus</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Prints</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    <!--END DROP DOWN -->  
     <li>&#124;</li>
     <li><a href="#">Partner</a></li>
     <li>&#124;</li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     <li>&#124;</li>
     <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
     <li>&#124;</li>
     <li><a href="#" style="word-spacing:-1px">Past Campaigns</a>                       </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <!--</div>-->
   <!-- END TOP NAV -->

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a css rule for all ul elements to have padding-left of 235px.  So your submenu ul is accordingly widened.  Also, ul elements have default padding thanks to browsers.  Set that particular ul padding to 0 and then dial it in to taste.

Update: I've gone ahead and added the css to just give the ul.drop-nav a padding:0

```css
/* Generated by Font Squirrel (http://www.fontsquirrel.com) on September 4, 2014 */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'revolution';
    src: url('../fonts/revolution/revolution-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/revolution/revolution-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/revolution/revolution-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/revolution/revolution-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/revolution/revolution-webfont.svg#revolutionrevolution') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}



/*************************
Start Styling
*************************/

body#pages {
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-image: url('../images/pages_bg.jpg');
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}


#wrapper_2 {
 width: 1024px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: auto;
 
}

/*************************
SHOP MENU
*************************/
#shop_menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: -90px;
    margin-top: 42px;
}

#shop_menu ul{
    padding-left: 235px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#shop_menu li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 3px;
}

#shop_menu a{
    font-family: 'revolution';
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #0c5066; /*Teal Blue*/
    text-decoration: none;
}

#shop_menu a:hover{
    color: #d8512b; /*Orange Red*/
    
}

/*----- DROP DOWN -----*/

#dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.drop-nav {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.drop-nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
#dropdown:hover > .drop-nav {
  display: block;
  background-color: #888;
 
}

/*  SET DROPDOWN .drop-nav UL PADDING TO 0  */
#dropdown ul.drop-nav {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body id="pages">

  <div id="wrapper_2">

        <!--MENU -->
   <div id="shop_menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="mockup.html">Home</a></li>
     <li>&#124;</li>
     <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
     <li>&#124;</li>
    <!--DROP DOWN --> 
     <li id="dropdown"><a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
      <ul class="drop-nav">
       <li><a href="#">Womens</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Mens</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Womens Plus</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Mens Plus</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Prints</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    <!--END DROP DOWN -->  
     <li>&#124;</li>
     <li><a href="#">Partner</a></li>
     <li>&#124;</li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     <li>&#124;</li>
     <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
     <li>&#124;</li>
     <li><a href="#" style="word-spacing:-1px">Past Campaigns</a>                       </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <!--</div>-->
   <!-- END TOP NAV -->

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you! i was hoping it was a "duh" kind of thing :)

Comment: NP - there are lots of hidden HTML and CSS 'gotchas' that you just have to pick up along the way.  Please vote me up if this was useful.